# C++17 Tuple Unpacking

Tags: c++, tuples, c++17

I am trying to unpack a tuple and use the results to assign into members. Is it possible to do that in idiomatic C++17?

I realize that `std::tie` exists but I am trying to utilize C++17 features and not default to older features nor the old way (`std::get<N>(tuple)`)

```
tuple<A, vector<A>> IO(){
     //IO happens here
     return {var, vec};
}

class foo{
public:
    foo();
private:
    A var;
    vector<A> vec;
};

foo::foo(){
    //this line here: I want to assign var and vec from IO()
    [var, vec] = IO();
}
```

Comment: Can you tun this into a [mcve]?  The code loos like it could work but it is missing stuff.

Comment: Why ignore the previous versions? I mean are you going to stop using virtual functions because they were in '98?

Comment: @GemTaylor A less hostile interpretation of the question might be: "We have structured bindings in C++17. Does there exist a new, nicer way for me to solve this problem, or do I have to use the old way?"

Comment: @Barry, That is exactly what I am asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really. Structured bindings can only *declare* new names, it cannot *assign* to existing ones.

Best would be to just do this:

```
foo() : foo(IO()) { } // delegate to a constructor, calling IO

foo(std::tuple<A, vector<A>>&& tup) // manually unpack within this constructor
  : var(std::get<0>(std::move(tup)))
  , vec(std::get<1>(std::move(tup)))
{ }
```

---

If `A` happens to be default constructible and move assignable, then yeah this works too:

```
foo() {
    std::tie(var, vec) = IO();
}
```

If `A` happens to *not* be default constructible, then you could use `optional` to add that extra state:

```
struct foo {
    std::optional<A> var;
    std::vector<A> vec;

    foo() {
        std::tie(var, vec) = IO();
    }
};
```

None of these are particularly great.

Comment: Well that is unfortunate, there is always hope for C++2X

Comment: And probably make the tuple accepting ctor private.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing a similar structure for unpacking tuples into inline variable declarations, that seems to solve this case here as well.
As explained before, Structured bindings can only declare new names, but cannot assign to existing ones.
However, the proposed solution requires including a Header Only library intuples (Disclaimer, I'm the author!) and the solution itself is unfortunately an Ugly MACRO (sorry, could not do it in plain c++ constexpr).
Like I said, my use case is different, but to solve it here, instead of desired `[var, vec] = IO()`, just do `UNPACK_TUPLE_TO2(IO(), var, vec)`.

Full example:

```
#include <intuple/UnpackTuple.hpp> // get this header from project
tuple<A, vector<A>> IO(){
     //IO happens here
     return {var, vec};
}

class foo{
public:
    foo();
private:
    A var;
    vector<A> vec;
};

foo::foo(){
    //this line here: I want to assign var and vec from IO()
    // [var, vec] = IO();
    UNPACK_TUPLE_TO2(IO(), var, vec)
    // Expands to
    // var = std::get<0>(IO());
    // vec = std::get<1>(IO());
}
```

I think it is quite bad as it is, since IO() will be executed twice!
So, at least, one should assign locally first:

```
auto t = IO();
UNPACK_TUPLE_TO2(t, var, vec)
// Expands to
// var = std::get<0>(t);
// vec = std::get<1>(t);
```

It's easy to create a variation of this macro to automatically create such local variable before tuple assignment... but it's quite a workaround and not a beautiful solution like structured bindings :)
The macro definition is:

```
#define UNPACK_TUPLE_TO1(TObj, VAR0) \
  VAR0 = std::get<0>(TObj);
#define UNPACK_TUPLE_TO2(TObj, VAR0, VAR1) \
  VAR0 = std::get<0>(TObj);                \
  VAR1 = std::get<1>(TObj);
```

If one finds a better way, please let me know too :)
P.S.: open-source project is named intuples, check repo: https://github.com/igormcoelho/intuples